# Rails: How to query records in different languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, machine-learning, deep-learning, translation

I have a Rails inventory app that is available to global users, allowing them to enter their own inventory information and query those of others.

- a British person in London adds 10 units of "bicycle" to the inventory table
- a Japanese person adds 2 units of 自転車 (bicycle in Japanese)
- a Vietnamese adds 5 units of xe dap (bicycle in Vietnamese)

The British person can query 'bicycle' and it will output all bicycles in the system (17 units) and can show the details of each in their original language, without the users classifying them beforehand. Likewise, the Japanese person can query '自転車', which will show all bicycles.

How can this be done?

The globalize gem requires users to manually translate each record so it's not the correct way. I've heard about machine learning and deep learning but I don't know if it's the right solution for this.

So if stackoverflow is not the right place to ask this? Where should I ask? Quora does not allow long questions.

Comment: Machine learning/deep learning/AI is currently just a buzzword. It requires a lot of (sample) data and a lot of work. Unless you can provide that it’s going to be difficult, especially to automatically generate translations...

Comment: One way can be to ask the user for the English translation for every non english word added.  That way, you can use the English word as the primary/foreign key.

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes you need to help yourself first by reading a book on the topic, or asking someone you know. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question, fix the obvious shortcomings, and get it re-opened.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Machine learning does not seem like a proper solution in this context since you don't have enough experience with it and it's a complex matter to just start with it and learn enough to apply to a real life problem.

Here are a few solutions you could implement today, as long as you understand the requirements and the up/downs for each, you will have to figure those out by yourself.

Since I don't have enough information about your system I'll try and generalize it to something that's likely.

Solutions:

1.Define a limited number of items for your system, like Bike and add
    them to a config file or in a items database, each item having it's
    unique id and when a user will have to add something they will have
    to select from your list. Have a Other item as a catch-all, and
    maybe provide a note so the users can add anything to recognize the
    item.

2.Similar to the above solution but you give the users a way to add new items into the system, so you have 10 standard items and every user can add items to the site (those being moderated) and other users will have access to them.

3.Have a solid search system in place like Elasticsearch (or anything else), and when the user create items you index that item in the language that is entered, and then use Google translation API (or another translation service) to translate them in all the languages you need and index those for search as well.

I think solution **1** is the best if you are able to implement it followed by solution **2**.

Comment: It would be helpful for myself and maybe others that see my answer if a comment is added as well explaining why my answer is considered "bad" in the voter's opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Instead of defining a limited number of items, I decided to just limit the number of language translations to just English and Japanese. So each record will have additional columns: name_en and name_jp in addition to the name column. So name "bicycle" will have name_jp "自転車" from either Google's translate API based on the users's locale or manually translated by staff. So Inventory "ピカチュウカード will have name_en "Pikachu card" and no Vietnamese translation.

Comment: Sounds good, it's always better to start small and then improve on that when you have more information. If you can do that manual translation is always better (from a good translator of course), or at least check the translation before approving the item.